# Dim ACAD as OBject VS ACADAPPLICATION

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, autocad

In [this article](http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=245944) at the end of the vba code on how to open an AutoCAD drawing using VBA, the author talks about

```
Dim ACAD as OBJECT
```

The author states that is will work "fine" but states a better choice would be:

```
Dim ACAD as AcadApplication
```

Why is this a better choice since you would have to load the "AutoCAD Version Type Library"?

I have no understanding of OBJECT, CLASS, LIBRARY or ACADAPPLICATION as variable types.  My knowledge is limited to basically integer, Boolean, string, array, long...basically stuff I would have picked up from Fortran or Turbo Pascal.

Comment: first one is called `late binding`. the object is defined at run time.  the second one is called `early binding`. the object is defined when it is typed in. the compiler and the VBA editor (IDE) are aware of the object when you type in the code, which allows the editor to give you suggestions about the command properties (it is called intellisense) ..... type in the second line `Dim ACAD as AcadApplication`  .... then  on next line type `ACAD.` .... as soon as you type in the  period, you should see a list of methods and properties show up. ... makes it easier to choose the correct commands

Comment: OBJECT is a program entity that has properties and methods attached to it (look up OOP or object oriented programming) .... for example an excel worksheet can be manipulated through VBA by using its object.... for example the worksheet object has a `rows` property, so doing `print worksheet.rows` prints out the number of rows in the worksheet ....  it also has a `clear` method, so doing `worksheet.clear` deletes everything on the worksheet (i may be slightly off on the actual commands, ... it is meant to be a very basic explanation)

Comment: Thank you jsotola for shedding light on this and breaking it down to a simpler term for me